# Python renom module has same function/member name but labeled in different colors

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, module

I am using [renom](http://www.renom.in/) to implement some machine learning project. I notice there is methods/member within renom module that have same name, except in different colors. They also start with lower case and upper case.

For example, the following, the `rm` variable has `conv2d` and `Conv2d`, with different labels (navy c, and pink a)

[image]

Another example is `relu`:

[image]

I am just wondering what do those labels mean (members? methods? private? public? .....)? I am using Spyder with Anaconda. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These colored `.` completion markers are specific to Spyder's IDE. In this case, `C` in pink denotes a [c]lass object, while the `a` narker denotes an [a]ttribute. You can see the same thing if you assign a string to `s`, then do `s.`. You'll see both [a]ttributes and [m]ethods available for the string object.

Specifically regarding the two different things with the same name: from the renom docs, you can access the same functionality either by calling the function, or instantiating the object and then calling the same function (see below from the linked page). As to why it was designed that way, you'd have to ask the developers.

```
import renom as rm
import numpy as np


x = np.array([[1, -1]])
array([[ 1, -1]])
rm.elu(x)
elu([[ 1.  , -0.00632121]])


# instantiation
activation = rm.Elu()
activation(x)
elu([[ 1.  , -0.00632121]])
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.